# Don't understand cause of this TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I have the function below and I'm trying to call it inside a `while True:` loop:

```
def icaolist():
    c = conn3.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM icaolist")
    rows = c.fetchall()
    result = {}
    for row in rows:
        result[row[0]] = row[1]
    return result
```

The above function works well outside the loop, but when I try to put it inside it I got the following error:

```
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

I'm using this to call it:

```
while True:
    icaolist = icaolist()
    time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: `icaolist = icaolist()` - so you immediately shadow the function with the dictionary it returns. Why?

Comment: You can't have a variable with the same name as a function if that's your intent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`icaolist = icaolist()`

You can't have the same name for the dictionary and the function.